# Connection string works on Web Server but not locally

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I have created a test **SQL Server 2005** database on my test Web Server. I have an **ASP.Net MVC 4** web application also on that test server which connects to the test sql server database and it does this without any problems.

Now, I am trying with the local copy of the MVC application on my PC, to connect to the test database on the test Web Server. I thought I could just use the same connection string as the MVC app on the Web Server uses, however, when I copy that connection string and put it into the web config of my local MVC application, attempt to connect, and I get the following error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Why would the connection string work for the MVC application on the test server, but not for my local copy of the MVC application?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would the connection string work for the MVC application on the
>   test server, but not for my local copy of the MVC application?

Because there's a firewall preventing your computer from accessing this SQL server. Or maybe the SQL server is on a completely different network from your computer and is simply not directly accessible.

Talk to your network/SQL Server administrator for assistance.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is a firewall issue.